# Criação de objetos em Python a partir do banco de dados

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, design-pattern

Estou aprendendo Python agora e quero criar um objeto a partir de informações que pego do banco de dados, somente passando o ID do usuário.

Estou usando o SQL Azure e o driver pyodbc. Está funcionando direitinho, porém gostaria de saber se esse é o jeito certo para esse tipo de situação, ou se já há algum "padrão" definido.

Classe usuário:

```
import pyodbc
from modulos import db

class User:
    def __init__(self, idusuario):
        query = """SELECT IDUSUARIO, CPF, EMAIL, NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO
                FROM USUARIO WHERE IDUSUARIO = ?;"""

        cursor = db.connection.cursor()
        row = cursor.execute(query, (idusuario)).fetchone()

        self.idusuario = row.IDUSUARIO
        self.cpf = row.CPF
        self.email = row.EMAIL
        self.nome = row.NOME
        self.sobrenome = row.SOBRENOME
        self.data_nascimento = row.DATA_NASCIMENTO

    def __repr__ (self):
        return "idusuario: {}, cpf: {}, email: {}, nome: {}, sobrenome: {}, data de nascimento: {}.".format(self.idusuario, self.cpf, self.email, self.nome, self.sobrenome, self.data_nascimento)
```

Classe App:

```
from user import User

usuario = User(1)

print(usuario)
```

Answer (score 1):

Em geral você não quer que instanciar seu objeto no Python tenha o efeito colateral de emitir uma query para o banco  -  O jeito "padrão" então seria ter uma função `__init__` que receba os parâmetros - pode ser como um dicionário, e configure os valores -

E uma outra parte do código que faça a query ao banco. Essa outra parte do código pode até fazer parte da classe do seu objeto, como um "classmethod" - mas ai fica claro que ela vai consultar o banco:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, idusuario=None, cpf=None, email=None, nome=None, sobrenome=None, data_nascimento=None):

        self.idusuario = idusuario
        self.cpf = cpf
        self.email = email
        self.nome = nome
        self.sobrenome = sobrenome
        self.data_nascimento = data_nascimento

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, id):
        query = """SELECT IDUSUARIO, CPF, EMAIL, NOME, SOBRENOME, DATA_NASCIMENTO
                FROM USUARIO WHERE IDUSUARIO = ?;"""

        cursor = db.connection.cursor()
        row = cursor.execute(query, (idusuario)).fetchone()
        return User(idusuario = row.IDUSUARIO, cpf=row.CPF, email=row.EMAIL sobrenome=row.SOBRENOME, data_nascimento=row.DATA_NASCIMENTO)
```

Claro que normalemente você não vai querer ficar se repetindo tanto, digitando os atributos de cada tabela, então pode usar as formas de introspecção do Python para buscar tanto o nome dos atributos num loop for - e isso pode ser genérico para mais de um modelo.

Mas até aí, você pode avançar bastante essa sua adaptação do modelo relacional para um objeto Python - pode colocar quanto trabalho quiser em cima disso - só que o mais usual mesmo é usar um adaptador Objeto Relacional (ORM)  já existente.

N caso do Python, o mais popular que existe é o [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) - ele realmente é um framework de ORM bem poderoso e completo - e recomendado.

A recomendação é usar o SQLAlchemy, mas só para te dar uma idéia de como seria uma base para os seus modelos usando a potencialidade de introspecção do Python - o código seguinte é equivalente ao exemplo que postei. Cada novo "model" com as mesmas capacidades poderia ser definido em 4 linhas de código a partir daqui:

```
class Base:
    _fields = []
    _table = ""
    _idcol = ""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls):
        query = """SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {idcol} = ?;""".format(
            fields=", ".join(upper(field) for field in cls._fields),
            table = cls._table,
            idcol=cls._idcol
        )
        cursor = db.connection.cursor()
        row = cursor.execute(query, (idusuario)).fetchone()
        return cls(**{field:getattr(row, field.upper()) for field in cls._fields})

class User(Base):
    _fields = "IDUSUARIO CPF EMAIL NOME SOBRENOME DATA_NASCIMENTO".lower().split()
    _idcol = "ideusuario"
    _table = "USUARIO"
```