# Chamar atributos de um objeto em outra classe no python

Tags: sql, python

Eu sou iniciante no **python** e eu queria saber como chamo atributos de outro objeto em uma outra classe, pois no Java, por exemplo:

```
package model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FuncionarioDAO {
    Produto p;   // Essa linha... como faço isso em python?


    List<Produto> itens = new ArrayList<Produto>();


    public void Cadastrar(Produto p) {
        itens.add(p);
    }

    public void Remover(int codigo) {
        for(int i=0; i<itens.size(); i++) {
            Produto p = itens.get(i);
                if(p.getCodigo() == codigo) {
                    itens.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
           }
      }

     public void Alterar(Produto p) {
         Remover(p.getCodigo());
         Cadastrar(p);   
         }
}
```

Também tenho outra pergunta, eu tenho base de **POO**, só que eu não compreendo muito bem a interligação de banco de dados com a aplicação.

Chega uma hora que preciso passar os dados pro **SQL** e não sei o que fazer.

Alguém poderia me dar dicas?

Comment: Você fez mais de uma pergunta e uma delas pode ser respondida nesse link **http://pythonclub.com.br/gerenciando-banco-dados-sqlite3-python-parte1.html**

Comment: Não faltou um Inject nesse produto ? @Inject Produto p; ?

Comment: mas como faz em python? pq já testei desse jeito como mostrei e ele dá erro

Comment: Estou elaborando uma resposta

Answer (score 2):

Observe o exemplo a seguir:

**exemplo.py**

```
class Pessoa:

    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

    def setNome(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def setIdade(self, idade):
        self.idade = idade

    def getNome(self):
        return self.nome

    def getIdade(self):
        return self.idade
```

Para ter acesso ao objeto, seus atributos e métodos, basta importa-lo na classe em que você deseja:

**main.py**

```
from exemplo import Pessoa

pessoa = Pessoa('Roberto', '12')

pessoa.setNome('Paulo')
pessoa.setIdade('18')

print('O ' + pessoa.getNome() + ' possui ' + pessoa.getIdade() + ' anos.')
```

Para saber mais sobre os [imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) segue esse [site](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-criar-minha-primeira-classe-em-python/38912).
Existem formas diferentes de se importar uma classe ou um *objeto* :

```
from modulo import objeto // Trará apenas o objeto requerido
from modulo import objeto as ob // Trará o objeto com o nome de 'ob'
from modulo import * // Importa todas as classes do módulo.
```

Sua segunda pergunta se refere a persistência de dados usando o Python. Para isso a forma mais comum é usar **ORM** do inglês : Object-relational mappers , que são frameworks responsáveis por transpor os códigos **sql** para objetos que podem ser usados dentro da linguagem escolhida. 
O Hibernate é um exemplo de ORM para java que é muito conhecido no meio. Ja para Python um dos mais conhecidos é o [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org).

Links úteis:

- [Essa tread pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191983/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-objetos-em-python-a-partir-do-banco-de-dados)
- [Conheça outros ORM do python.](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html)

Comment: Na definição da classe Pessoa parece ter falhas na indentação. E preferiu utilizar *setters*/*getters* a *property* por algum motivo em específico?

Comment: Usei setters e getters pelo fato da Rafaela ter citado um exemplo em java, demonstrando um conhecimento prévio da linguagem. Achei valido usa-los para aproximar o exemplo dado da vivencia dela.

Answer (score 2):

Por exemplo em um arquivo chamado pessoa.py, você possui a classe Pessoas e deseja chamá-la em um arquivo main.py

**main.py**

```
class Usuario:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pessoa = Pessoa()
```

Caso queira chamar em uma função do seu novo arquivo:

```
class Usuario:
    def minha_funcao(self):
        pessoa = Pessoa()
```

Answer (score 1):

> eu queria saber como chamo atributos de outro objeto em uma outra classe

A linha que tu destacou está declarando um atributo da classe. No Python, a declaração é feita na primeira atribuição. Caso tu queira garantir que um atributo é criado antes de receber um valor específico, declare-o como `None` dentro do `__init__`.

```
class Teste():
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = None
```

> eu não compreendo muito bem a interligação de banco de dados com a aplicação.

Isso é muito abrangente pra caber numa resposta.

> Alguém poderia me dar dicas?

Pesquise tutoriais do SQLAlchemy.